# Simulate auto selection in a drop down in Shiny R application

Tags: r, shiny, populate

I have an application where based on the selection in a drop down, I am generating a plot. I want to know if I can make the selection auto so that, the program goes through all the values on click of a button and plots a chart based on the input.
Here is the code for the same.

ui.R

---

```
# ui.R

library(shiny)

ds <- read.csv(file="data/InPatient_Disease_Year_AgeGroup_Count_Shinycsv.csv",header = TRUE, sep = ",")
unq= unique(ds$CCS_DIAGNOSIS_DESCRIPTION,incomparables = FALSE)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Inpatient data by disease"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Select a disease."),

      selectInput("val", 
                  label = "Choose a disease",
                  choices =unq,
                  selected  ="ABDOMINAL HERNIA"
                  )
      ),

    mainPanel(plotOutput("map"))
  )
))
#Sys.sleep(3)
```

server.R

---

```
# server.R
library(shiny)

ds <- read.csv(file="data/InPatient_Disease_Year_AgeGroup_Count_Shinycsv.csv",header = TRUE, sep = ",")


shinyServer(
  function(input, output){

    output$map <- renderPlot({ 

      val=input$val

      if (is.null(val))
        return(NULL)
      age_grp <- c("0 to 17", "18 to 29", "30 to 49", "50 to 69", "70 or Older")
      colours <- c("red", "orange", "blue", "yellow", "green")
      #unq= unique(ds$CCS_DIAGNOSIS_DESCRIPTION,incomparables = FALSE)




        df= ds[ds$CCS_DIAGNOSIS_DESCRIPTION == val ,c("Year_Age_Y","Number.Of.Cases")]

        #barplot(df$`Number.Of.Cases`,names.arg = df$Year_Age_Y,ylab=val, col=colours,beside=TRUE,legend = age_grp)
        barplot(df$`Number.Of.Cases`,main=val,names.arg = df$Year_Age_Y, las=2,space=0.5,mar=c(9.1, 5.1, 5.1, 1.1),col=colours,beside=TRUE,font.axis=1,ps=2,legend = age_grp,args.legend = list(x = "topleft", bty = "n",cex=0.6, inset=c(-0.05, -0.10)))
    } )

  }

)
```

Please let me know if this can be achieved in Shiny. Basically I trying to generate a running plot form a file for all the rows in the file. The action can be triggered by clicking on a button.

Thanks,
Tej

Comment: I am not sure why you would need a `selectInput` then? Since you do not want to select a specific value from this input, but use them all. And another question: Lets say you have n values in your `selectInput`, do you want then as the desired output n plots below each other?

Comment: Do you want to update the same plot by clicking a button?